# Sum of a Sequnce

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

How to find this sum $$ \sum_{i+j+k=n} \ G_i \cdot G_j \cdot G_k \ for \ all \ i,j,k > 0, $$
$$ G_i = i \cdot F_i, $$
where Fi - ith number Fibonacci, F0=0, F1=1

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you mean $G_i = i\cdot F_i$ and $\sum\limits_{i+j+k=n} G_i \cdot G_j \cdot G_k \cdot i \cdot j \cdot k$? And is $F_1 = 0$ or $1$?

Comment: If you want to use lower index, you can do it like this: `G_i=i\cdot F_i` $G_i=i\cdot F_i$.